# Start server in current directory (php/apache)

Tags: php, python, macos, apache, terminal

Apparently, you can start a temporary server with Python, by using:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Is there a way to do this for PHP and Apache? e.g. one command which will serve the current folder as the localhost? On Mac.

Comment: Since Apache is a webserver, all you need to do is start the Apache service and you're good to go so this question is a bit vague considering Apache is a one-liner all on it's own, however you can't do more than start the service :)

Comment: @Torxed there are many, many issues/annoyances with having to store server files in a different location to your working directory

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can start PHP development server in versions 5.4 and above with:

```
php -S localhost:8008
```

I don't think Apache supports anything similar (being itself a web server), but PHP dev server is enough for testing scripts, including serving static contents.

Comment: [PHP Built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) is `single-threaded process`, all your request will be serial

Answer (score 5):

PHP 5.4 added a simple web server to the PHP cli. You can start it with `php -S <addr>:<port>` it will serve the current directory on address `<addr>` over port `<port>`

Answer (score 0):

In terminal, head to the directory with the index.php file (normally) and run the following, according to;

```
cd /Users/macuser/folder123/myphpsite
php -S localhost:8000
```

Now that index.php is served and locally available in a browser via the URL address

```
http://localhost:8000
```

*After a few errors I feel it's a good idea to simply give a less ambiguous answer (imho) without editing such old and approved answers that suits others.*